# React: setItems Error when using localStorage

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

When I am using the setItem() Method, i get no errors and everything is working fine. But when I try to retrieve objects via the getItem() Method, im getting the error: "src\components\UserCourses.js   Line 33:8:  'setItems' is not defined  no-undef"

```
//LocalStorage
  useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('basket', JSON.stringify(basket));
}, [basket]);

useEffect(() => {
  const basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('basket'));
  if (basket) {
   setItems(basket);
  }
}, []);
```

basket is my empty array at the start, where i put in items.

```
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
function UserCourses ({id, name, prof, language}) {
    const [{basket}, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const goCourseDetail = () => navigate(`/course/id=${id}`)
    const removeFromBasket = () => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'REMOVE_FROM_BASKET',
            id: id,
        });
    }
useEffect(() => {
      localStorage.setItem('basket', JSON.stringify(basket));
    }, [basket]);

    useEffect(() => {
      const basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('basket'));
      if (basket) {
       setItems(basket);
      }
    }, []);

//Provider
import React, {createContext, useContext, useReducer} from 'react';

//data layer
export const StateContext = createContext();


//Provider
export const StateProvider = ({reducer, initialState, children}) => (
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
);



//use inside of a component
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

Comment: Did you mean setBasket(basket)? You need to define the setter. like const [items, setItems] = useState("initial value")

Comment: i changed const [{basket}, dispatch,] = useStateValue();    to
                const [{basket}, dispatch, setBasket] = useStateValue();
and then did setBasket(basket);
now error is gone, but I am getting a blank page when I wanna see the added Items in the basket

Comment: I don't know what useStateValue is. Can you share the whole code? the code where you define what useStateValue is and where you define it in UserCourses

Comment: I shared it. Hope you can find something =)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with localStorage in a shopping cart I was developing, if it helps. I was able to solve my problem, with the next code:

```js
    const initialState = []
    const [carrito, setCarrito] = useState(initialState)
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const carritoLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('carrito'))
        if (carritoLS) {
          setCarrito(carritoLS)
        }
      }, [])
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (carrito !== initialState){
          localStorage.setItem('carrito', JSON.stringify(carrito))
        }
      }, [carrito])
```

Comment: I do not get the error anymore, but when i refresh my page (with the added items) the items are gone...